# Is there a way to browse encrypted files when using Android's File Based Encryption (FBE)?

Tags: encryption

I've learned that my Google Pixel 2 uses File Based Encryption (FBE) to encrypt my files. I was wondering if there is some way to see these files in their encrypted form. Can I mount the encrypted and decrypted on a rooted stock rom at the same time?

If so, can I decrypt my files on any other device than my Pixel? What about a pc?

Comment: Is your device unlocked (oem unlock) or rooted? Because on a regular locked stock device without root I don't think that you can get access to the unencrypted data.

Comment: My device is unlocked and rooted with the latest stock rom.

Comment: Then I think the best option would be to install and run a custom recovery ROM. Some custom recovery ask for the password, however if you don't provide the password you may be able to get access to the RAW encrypted data.

Comment: What I am trying to archive is a way to backup my files in an encrypted way. Thus, I can't use a custom recovery ROM, because I want to upload those files somewhere.

Comment: Usually you do a backup because your device can get lost or defect. As the encryption key is AFAIR usually bound to your device the backup would be useless in such a case. Better backup the decrypted files and encrypt the data in the backup files.